# A specific problem with mathastext (last updated of 2019/11/14 november, using console of MikTeX)

Tags: errors, compilation-error, updating, miktex2.9, miktex-update

This afternoon I have update with MikTeX console the latest updated packages. Yesterday everything worked well but now I get this error message. Why?
Tomorrow I will have to give the test to my students but I can't compile it now.

```
! LaTeX Error: Command '\mst@ltbar@mvnormal' already defined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                       
l.5     \begin
              {document}
?
```

---

### EDIT: By the 2nd comment of the very very good user @David Carlisle I have put your MWE code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[italic,basic, default mathsizes]{mathastext} 
\MTlettershape{sl}\Mathastext 
\begin{document} 
Test document
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi, I have always used this code to create a test for my students. Until yesterday, I've never had problems with compilation. This afternoon I did the update and the .tex file no longer works. I have not undersood the cause of the error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have always the same error **! LaTeX Error: Command `\mst@ltbar@mvnormal' already defined. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  ...           
l.1 ...stext} \MTlettershape{sl}\Mathastext \begin
                                                  {document} \end{document}
?**

Comment: The culprit seems to be line 13: `\MTlettershape{sl}\Mathastext`. Commenting it, I obtain a normal compilation.

Comment: @Bernard yep that's why it is in the MWE in the above  comment (the OP should fix the example in the question)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had entered a lot of code thinking that the problem of the error was related to the whole preamble. What is the reason to use `nohbar`. In fact, using `nohbar` option solve the problem. Why with last update of `mathastext` package `\MTlettershape{sl}\Mathastext` it is not work. What is the important rule of it?

Comment: @Bernard In fact, removing `\MTlettershape{sl}\Mathastext` all works correctly. +1 for the comment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you kindly insert a complete answer also referring to your comments that I vote and accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that adding the `nohbar` option avoids the issue as in

```
\usepackage[italic,basic, default mathsizes,nohbar]{mathastext}
```

But getting an undefined command error looks like a bug in the package, you should report it to the package author.

Comment: Thank you very very much. As I had already mentioned the problem was born only yesterday when I downloaded the updates. But should I send an email to the author of the package or where should I report this bug?

Comment: @Sebastiano `texdoc mathastext` shows the authors email in the title, (if you replace ``at` by `@`)

Comment: I thank you for everything and I always reward the efforts of every single user. +1 for everything.